# Flatlist is empty and array has values in it

Tags: react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I filled an array with `querySnapshot` but flatlist doesn't render anything

Tried to change `renderItem` code

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  var rootref = firebase.firestore().collection("deneme");
  var wholeData = []
  rootref.get().then(function(querySnapshot){
      querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
        wholeData.push(doc.data())
      });
  });
};

render() {
  return (
    <View>
      <FlatList
         data={this.wholeData}
         renderItem={({item}) => <Text>{item.isim}, {item.soyisim}</Text>}
      />
    </View>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You will have to use `setState` to notify the component that the data has changed. Change your code to do the following:

```
 constructor(props) {
      super(props);

      this.state = {
       data: []
      };

      var rootref = firebase.firestore().collection("deneme");
      rootref.get().then(querySnapshot => 
       const wholeData = querySnapshot.map(doc => doc.data()));

       // notify your component that the data has changed
       this.setState({
        data: wholeData
       })
    };

 render() {
  return (
    <View>
      <FlatList
         data={this.state.data} // get your data from the state
         renderItem={({item}) => <Text>{item.isim}, {item.soyisim}</Text>}
      />
    </View>
  );
```

This way as soon as you have received the wholeData, the FlatList will update.

Comment: Thanks but now im having another error querySnapshot is not a function.

Comment: querySnapshot is just an object. You should check your code if you are calling it as a function by mistake.

Comment: I copied the entire code. const part is giving an error.